# Can not convert ActionScript3 to c#

Tags: c#, arrays, actionscript-3

Hallo I am trying to implement sorting function in c# (I wan to sort the array)

```
card_codes.sort(function() { return 2 * Math.floor(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1 } );
```

This is how ActionScript sorts array of integers in script and every time after first sort it starts with 301

but When I try to sort same array in c# it always starts with 101

here is how I sort it in c#

```
Array.Sort(PlayngCardCodes, (f1, f2) => 0.CompareTo(2 * (int)Math.Floor(rng.NextDouble()) == 0 ? -1 : 1));
```

can anyone tell me how to exactly rewrite actionscript sort to get the same result?

Comment: This is not any sort I've ever seen... Is it just me or does no sort worth the effort ever use a RNG?

Comment: I think he's actually trying to shuffle. Not sure that using a sort to implement a shuffle is such a hot idea, though. [Sort comparitors must be deterministic.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/20/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Actionscript version is not my code it was written by someone but I was asked to rewrite the same code in c# I am not good at AcrionScript but what i see is that every time this method is run it sorts array i a way that it always starts with 301

Comment: I don't know much about ActionScript either, but from what I see, you're still randomly generating values to decide the order of elements. Unless you're doing a Bogosort, you're shuffling the deck. And if you're always getting 301, perhaps ActionScript's RNG is not that good... Again, take that with a grain of salt, I have no experience in ActionScript

Comment: Math.random() is in range [0, 1), so Math.floor(Math.random()) is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionScript code is broken

```
Math.random()// will result in a number from 0 to 1 like so
//0.40654489677399397
```

When you floor any number it will round it down.
for example

```
0.40654489677399397 floored-->0
```

in otherwords

```
trace(Math.floor(0.40654489677399397) )// output is 0
```

So to sum it up

```
trace( Math.floor( Math.random() ) )// output is always 0


trace( 2 * Math.floor(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1 ) // output is always 1
```

I do not know c# but I would think you need to fix your source before you try to convert it.
However, since the ActionScript output is always 1 just make you c# function always return a 1 and be done with it :)

[EDIT]
Well I ran a test and the output is odd. Although, its not the original array probably due to the type of sorting that is being done in AS3

```
var card_codes:Array = new Array(2,467,8,342,37,7,6789,34,234,2)
card_codes.sort(function() { return 2 * Math.floor(Math.random()) ? -1 : 1 } );
trace(card_codes)// output is always 7,2,6789,8,34,37,234,2,342,467
```

Comment: Does not flor rounds to its closet higher number? for example if code is 0.786654488774 I think output will be 1
[link](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary456.html)

Comment: @Rati_Ge sorry bud you are wrong go ahead and loop trace( Math.floor( Math.random() ) ) 100,000 times you will see nothing but a 0 show up

Comment: @Rati_Ge actually it will output a 1 only when the random number is 1 but that is 1 in 100000000000000000 chances. Better chances at winning the loto

Comment: I sad that theoretically it might do that right? and what I do not understand is that why  that "smart coder" who wrote that script will never return 1 I am in a very difficult situation now as I need to convert that code very quickly

Comment: @Rati_Ge my point is the AS3 code is broken and does not work since you have to copy the code as is then just mimic what it does and always set it to 1 in c#

Comment: @Rati_Ge the AS3 sorting function is not sorting anything the resulting array is the initial array

Comment: very very strange can you do a little test and tell me if something changes? try to run the following code

var limit:int = 28;
than create some array which will be initialized with data
that write do...while loop and after calling sort decries limit by one and in while portion check if limit is greater than 0

Comment: I edited my answer and ran a small test for you ( I didn't understand the one you wanted) the output is always the same order.

Comment: convert this card_codes.sort(function() { return 1; } ); to c# and you will have the exact same results. Assuming that C# uses the same type of sorting that AS3 does.

Comment: wehll you can make your own sorting but as I was told to exactly convert AS code and only adopt it to c# language that makes some problem as AS code is not correct.

Comment: I think the AS3 code would be more feasible if Math.round( ) was used instead of Math.floor( )

Comment: ok and it always starts with 7 how can you explain this kin of sorting?

Comment: It's been a long time since I studied the types of sorts. But from the looks of of it is taking the first element and comparing with the middle element. Then splitting it from there.

Answer (score 1):

[You should not use a comparison function which might give two different answers for the same input.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/20/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-one.aspx)

If you want to shuffle, you should use [a shuffle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), not a sort.

Comment: can you pleas explain a bit more about this? I understand your point but in c# it is a little bit different every example I have seen uses sort and orderby with lambda

Comment: Using a sort and orderby with lambdas is a fine way to sort in general. The problem is that your lambda expression is using a RNG that will not always sort the array. C# has Quick Sort already built into the .Net framework, if you truly want a sort (and not a shuffle), use it.

Comment: I know but I forgot to mention that array is already sorted so it starts like 101,102,103...301,302,303

Comment: So you're shuffling the cards?

Comment: that's right but I want to do exactly what actionscript does and I want the same order as actinscript method returns

Comment: You want to re-implement their bug? :)

Comment: :) hehe good remark. but the point here is that even I wrote My own AI for game which really shuffles cards and works like a charm. the fact is that customer thinks that old version was better. I was forced to exactly convert actionscript to c#. that's why I faced with this problem